# Why some hyperlinks on TeX do not open by click/Ctrl+click while others do?

Tags: hyperref, moderncv

I have a couple of hyperlinks on my `moderncv` letter and all I can open via click or Ctrl+click except one which only open via right-click>open in new tab/window. Why such a thing happen and how to fix it? I am using `\href` command for all hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}                           
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=3cm, bottom=5cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{0.85\textwidth}}
\setlength{\footskip}{120pt} 
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                         
\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data



\recipient{98765 }{}

\date{\today}


\opening{}
\closing{sincerely, \vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip} 

 this \href{ https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319262915_Justifiability_Destpite_Belief_Polarization_A_Disagreement-Based_Theory_of_Epistemic_Justification_Lund_December_2011}{\color{blue} hyperlink does not open directly} but this \href{https://philevents.org/event/show/405}{\color{blue} hyperlink does}.

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Comment: We'd need to see the difference between these two apparent behaviours. Also, what PDF reader/viewer do you use?

Comment: @Werner It is adobe pdf reader and I open in on the web by Chrome.

Comment: ...and how can we replicate this behaviour? Please provide a minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. We should be able to copy-and-paste-and-compile and reproduce your setup. Without that, it's difficult to address your vague problem.

Comment: I've **never** seen a version of Adobe reader with a right-click option to "open in new tab" (or window).  I *think* your reply to Werner should be that your PDF reader is Chrome (for these purposes)

Comment: @Werner I added an example.

Comment: @ChrisH I added an example.

Comment: I assume removing the space at the beginning of the first `href` doesn't help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the leading blank in the first link.  After deleting it my PDF viewer SumatraPDF can directly open the link, with your MWE not.

With the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}                           
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=3cm, bottom=5cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\recomputefootlengths}{%
  \setlength{\footwidth}{0.85\textwidth}}
\setlength{\footskip}{120pt} 
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                         
\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data



\recipient{98765 }{}

\date{\today}


\opening{}
\closing{sincerely, \vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip} 

this 
\href{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319262915_Justifiability_Destpite_Belief_Polarization_A_Disagreement-Based_Theory_of_Epistemic_Justification_Lund_December_2011}{\color{blue} hyperlink does not open directly} 
but this 
\href{https://philevents.org/event/show/405}{\color{blue} hyperlink does}.

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

I can open the link without problems with SumatraPDF.  I do not have Acrobat, I can not test it with this viewer. Please test it on your system ...